# Jstree - adding multiple new nodes

Tags: jstree

I've a jsTree, that I am populating like this

$('#jstree').jstree();

$data is a json_encoded array

After the tree is created, is there a way to add multiple nodes to the tree, say on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 var ref = $('#jstree').jstree(true);
 //we bound it with .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {...
 var sel = data.node.id; 
 ref.create_node(sel, { "id": keyId, "text": mytext, "rel": "key", "type": "key",  });
```